# Moving file uploads to specific folder with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, upload, image-uploading

I am having issues getting my image uploads to move to the proper folders. When I upload them they just dump into the main img folder instead of going to the specific subfolder.

Here is the code I have:

```
            $rental = new Rental;

            $rental->title = $request->title;
            $rental->name = $request->name;
            $rental->description = $request->description;

             if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
                $image = $request->file('image');
                $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = public_path('img/rentals' . $filename);
                 Image::make($image)->save($path);

                 $rental->image = $filename;
                }               

            $rental->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `/` in your `$path`. The following line...

```
$filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

will generate a string, something like `123456789.jpg`. Then in the next line you're doing...

```
$path = public_path('img/rentals' . $filename);
```

which joins together `img/rentals` and `123456789.jpg`, resulting in `img/rentals123456789.jpg`. Notice that `.` which concatenates two strings. You're then passing the resulting string to `public_path` which will refer to a folder in your public directory named `img` and a filename `rentals123456789.jpg`.

To solve your problem you just need to stick a forward slash in between:

```
$filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$path = public_path('img/rentals/' . $filename);
```

which will result in a folder `img/rentals` inside your public path and a filename of `123456789.jpg`.

Comment: You're welcome :) please consider accepting if this helped!